# JNA 3.2.7 - CallWindowProc - Where is it?

Tags: java, jna

I'm having troubles with the latest version of the JNA library. I used to call `CallWindowProc` by `User32.INSTANCE.CallWindowProc`. The process is the same as the one described here: [Create a native Windows window in JNA and some GetWindowLong with GWL_WNDPROC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041174/create-a-native-windows-window-in-jna-and-some-getwindowlong-with-gwl-wndproc)

In the latest version *3.2.7* I can't find anymore `CallWindowProc`.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Seems strange the JNA people didn't move this feature somewhere else..

Answer (score -1):

Looks like this method has been removed from 3.2.7 ,though i don't know why.If you want to use it , use an SVN client to checkout the latest source for JNA and add the function to the User32 class and recompile platform.jar.

Comment: The existing interfaces are designed so that you can easily extend them and declare just the routines of interest.

The windows APIs have been extracted to a separate archive called platform.jar, although it looks like CallWindowProc has not been added there.